# SMLNJ: Operator & operand don't agree [tycon mismtach] - for list assignment

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have written the following function in SMLNJ:

```
fun f(id : int, l : int list list) =
  let
    val i : int = length(l) - 1
  in
    while i > 0 do
    (
      if (exists(id, List.nth(l, i))) then
        List.hd(List.nth(l, i)) := 1
      else();

      i = i - 1
    )
end;
```

The error received is as follows:

```
Error operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: 'Z ref * 'Z
  operand:         int * [int ty]
  in expression:
    List.hd (List.nth (l,i)) := 1
```

I am aware that the operator domain is what the function expects while the operand is what is provided.
I presume this occurs as an `int` cannot be assigned to a `list` type. However, I am unclear as to how `List.hdList.nth(l, i))` would result in anything other than an `int`.

Please advise on how I may fix this error and the supporting logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SML/NJ's error message does not make this terribly clear. If you were to put this code inside the [Moscow ML](http://mosml.org/) REPL, and include the function `contains` which you've used but not defined, you'd get the following error:

```
! Toplevel input:
!         List.hd(List.nth(l, i)) := 1
!                          ^
! Type clash: expression of type
!   int list list
! cannot have type
!   'a ref list list
```

Your program fails because you're treating *int* values as if they were *int ref* values.

In functional programming you generally try to avoid mutable variables (*ref* values).

To elaborate on the problem you're having:

- `List.hd(List.nth(l, i)) := 1` means "Set the reference returned by `List.hd(List.nth(l, i))` to `1`. Since `l` is an *int list list*, then `List.nth(l, i)` returns the `i`th element of that (or crashes), which is an *int list*. Then `List.hd(...)` takes the 1st element of that (or crashes), which is an *int*. Not an *int ref*.

  For this line to work, you'd need for `l : int ref list list`.

  But you don't want that.
- `i = i - 1` is a boolean expression that returns `true` if `i` is equivalent to itself minus 1. This is not true for any *int*. You probably intend to subtract 1 from `i` and place the result in `i`, but you can't, because `i` is not a mutable variable, and the operator for updating a *ref* is called `:=`.

---

If your problem were to convert the list

```
val m = [ [ 1, 2, 3 ],
          [ 4, 5, 6 ],
          [ 7, 8, 9 ] ]
```

into the list

```
val n = [ [ 1, 2, 3 ],
          [ 1, 5, 6 ],
          [ 1, 8, 9 ] ]
```

then a short way to do this would be to use `List.map`:

```
val n = List.map (fn row => 1 :: List.drop (row, 1)) m
```

A more manual way that practices *recursion* and *pattern matching* over *iteration* like `while ... do` (that only works if you have mutable variables) and *partial functions* like `List.hd` and `List.nth` (that might crash) could be:

```
fun f [] = []
  | f (row::m) = (1 :: List.drop (row, 1)) :: f m

val n = f m
```

If you want a mutable version, consider the [`Array2`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/array2.html) module instead of an *int list list*.

Here is one `Array2` solution where the cursor is increased using recursion:

```
fun appulate f from to =
    if from > to then ()
    else (f from; appulate f (from+1) to)

fun f col m =
    appulate (fn row => Array2.update (m, row, col, 1))
             0 (Array2.nRows m - 1)

fun show m =
    Array2.appi Array2.RowMajor (fn (_, col, c) =>
      print (Int.toString c ^ (if col + 1 = Array2.nCols arr then "\n" else "" )))
      {base=arr,row=0,col=0,nrows=NONE,ncols=NONE};


val m' = Array2.fromList m
val n' = f 0 m'
val _  = show n'
```

I realize that I haven't given any examples of a `while ... do`, or any collection of *int ref*s on which one operates with `ref`, `!` and `:=`.